# The usage of the title "Mr." along with other titles

Tags: names, titles

Could I put "Mr." along other title?

> Mr. DR. Alan Smith

Somebody may explain the usage of title Mr. before the name

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange Azhar, it's good practice to research your question first for instance with google, then you can write what you learned and what you still don't understand in your question from your research. This helps others that may be reading, helps pinpoint what you might not be understanding, and also shows some effort on your part.

Comment: In English, no.  In some other languages, yes.  *Herr Professor Doktor Schmitt".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.

Mr. (short for Mister) is a honorific. You can't string together honorifics. Thus, if a person is a doctor, "Dr." (short for doctor) replaces "Mr." If someone's a Captain, Inspector, or Reverend, then that replaces "Mr."

The President can be addressed as either Mr. President or President Trump, but never "Mr. President Trump."

Comment: What if a doctor is also a captain, or inspector, or becomes the president?

Comment: Pick one and stick with it. Unless you want to call them Doctor Captain and see how they'll react.

Comment: haha.. yes... but what i meant was... does one override the other.. like if a doctor (PhD) becomes a captain in army, would it be offensive to use Dr. (Or Capt.) in formal communication.. do the titles take precedence over one another.. e.g.  president would definitely be offended if referred to as anything else i think.. :)

Comment: @lukya: Yes, but this depends on a whole bunch of things. President trumps everything else, of course, no pun intended. Doctor would probably take precedence over Captain. And Captain is often more prestigious than Inspector - well, depending on the outfit, I guess.

Comment: Honorifics are strung together when naming someone formally. but not including 'Mr' which is what you call a man who doesn't have any other titles. This morning I saw a TV interview with the Dean of Westminster, the Very Rev Dr John Hall, who I imagine would be correctly addressed as Dr Hall.

Comment: Surely all this is highly contextual and varies depending on the local system of titles. Eg "Mr Justice Peter Smith" is the correct way to refer to Sir Peter Winston Smith (the Hon Mr Justice Peter Smith) even though in court he would be addressed as "my lord". I expect any system of titles (eg in the military) to have its own madly individual set of rules.

Sometimes titles merge (Professor > Dr) but sometimes they don't, eg Professor Sir Michael Atiyah, called "professor" in academic contexts but presumably "sir" in others.

Comment: @Francis; Sometimes "Sir Michael", but never "sir". There really is no quick and easy way to learn the system of honorifics and styles.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience other sources for this are made largely redundant by the three best: *Debrett's Correct Form*, *Burke's Peerage* and the church-bible-size office version of *Webster's Dictionary*, all offering immense detail on titles, styles of address and salutations for use in person or in correspondence.

In the 1965 film *The Sandpiper*, Richard Burton teaches us that, for instance, Reverend is not a title; it’s an adjective which qualifies a title. Many a priest is correctly addressed as Mr Priest, Rev Priest, The Rev Mr Priest or The Reverend Mr Priest but using Rev with Mr is only ‘allowed’ because the one is a title qualifying by the other.

The Dean of Wheresit, The Very Rev Dr Firsty Surname, drops Mr because of his superior Doctorate without which he would strictly be The Very Rev Mr Firsty Surname but normally formally only, as in official correspondence. Otherwise the ‘Dr’ might simply be omitted to avoid drawing attention to the fact he was a ‘mere Mr’… however obvious the omission made that.

Whether ‘Mr’ is an honorific or a title, Dr and Doctor are qualifications used as titles and considered 'superior’ to ‘mere’ Mr. Every-day English never uses two titles for ordinary people; she always defaults to the senior so Mr Dr or Dr Mr always become Dr.

In the British and US American Armies - see *M.A.S.H.* - Doctors and senior nurses happen historically to be Captains and what they call each other depends on whether they’re in the operating theatre, at a mess ball or on the billiard table… the more formal the situation, the more likely they will be addressed as Captain rather than Doctor… the Doctors or nurses are promoted to Majors or Colonels or on, but Doctor or Nurse remain their qualifications. Captain, Major, etc, are appointments and as such take precedence when talking to patients; their main function. Move from medicine into military administration and logistics and hear them start to use their ranks. While Captain Dr Tom and Major Dr Dick and Colonel Nurse Harriet are talking about a patient, they’re Doctors and Nurses. When they’re looking at budgets and staffing allocations and the like, they’re Captains and Majors and Colonels.

Mr President is never Mr President Surname because his appointment to the highest office in the land clearly outranks any personal name the man himself might expect to take to his grave. Unless you have equal rank as a visiting head of state, try picking ‘Mr Trump’ and sticking with it as a way to see how quickly you get shown out of the White House.

If I dare comment on anything so complex as the correct form for a High Court Judge it seems fairly clear that he might be termed My Lord in court and Judge by his staff in Chambers, and that The Hon Mr Justice is a composite title. Hon here fills the same adjectival place as Rev, now qualifying not the mere ‘Mr Personal Name’ but the much more senior ‘Mr Justice’ which since it clearly gives him the right to be addressed in court as My Lord, presumably outranks the mere Sir Firstname of his knighthood. For more on which watch *Judge John Deed*.

That's in English where Professor Dr is never used; the same fellow doing the same job in, say, Germany, would always be Professor Dr.

English happily uses Professor Sir Firstname Last precisely because Dr and Sir are not equivalent… Just as Professor is an appointment, Doctor is a professional or honorary qualification and the knighthood dubbing him Sir is a civic honour recognising special achievement.

Any of those might be complicated by military ranks where it might be almost unthinkable to find Private or Sergeant Lord Titlename - see *Dad's Army* - but its only recently and I doubt always that commissioned officers have stopped being being styled Lieutenant Lord Title, Major the Earl of  Placename or Field Marshal Prince Ironduke - and again, ranks titles and appointments are not the same things.

Of course we’re not going to refer to HRH The Prince Charles as Mr Windsor but neither will anyone normally make time to give him his full titles, which run something like HRH Prince Charles Philip Arthur George, The Prince of Wales, Duke of Cornwall, Duke of Rothesay, Earl of Chester, Earl of Carrick, Baron of Renfrew, Lord of the Isles and Great Steward of Scotland, KG, KT, GCB, OM, AK, QSO, ADC… he’s normally just Prince Charles or the Prince of Wales. (I chose Charles because his mum’s monikers are just too complicated…)

Comment: I wish you'd substitute "Priest" with  plain old *Smith*, or *Jones* I found `The Rev. Mr. Priest` slightly confusing until I realised it was being used as a placeholder.