# The derivation of titles of persons

Tags: honorifics

A general title which any person may use without any special qualification is the title 'Mister'. The titles 'Doctor' and 'Professor' would generally require a qualification.

My question is this;
are titles such as 'Doctor' and 'Professor' derived from the general title 'Mister', or perhaps put differently, are 'Doctor' and 'Professor' sub-categories of the more generic title 'Mister'?

To provide an analogy, if the title 'Mister' was as the word 'fruit' would the titles 'Doctor' and 'Professor' be as the words 'orange' and 'apple'?

---

I think most respondents have missed the point. Here is an example.

Joseph Biden and Vladimir Putin.

Is Joseph Biden, Mr Biden, President Biden or Mr President?

Is Vladimir Putin, Mr Putin, President Putin or Mr President?

The use of Mr President is prima-facie evidence the term President is a subcategory of the title Mister especially when used by a lawyer. Fundamentally Biden is a Mister but within that broad term he is more specifically, President.

I note a lack of comment on perhaps the most important aspect of this discussion. Few mentioned the important relation of a title, that being that it is always paired with a name, specifically a surname, with the exception of those that do not have a surname, such as certain members of royal families.

Greybeard's comment is quite pertinent and close to the mark. Many others are irrelevant, particular those from hand-wringer's who fret that I did not include the titles Miss and Mrs in my question. Those who feel it necessary to go out of their way to mention this are the one's with a problem. The rest of us take for granted that what is said about the term Mr applies equally to the terms Miss and Mrs and find that such a natural assumption to make that it literally goes without saying.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, using the term "derived". Surely "Doctor" is in a completely different **class** of honorific, which supersedes a generic "Mister"? (There's also the proper honorific for surgeons, which is "Mister", and is in the same class as "Doctor" superseding the generic "Mister".)

Comment: You are aware that women can be professors and doctors?

Comment: (I suspect someone is writing a data hierarchy for some kind of software, but would suggest for reasons given in GreenWhiteBlue's answer that you accept that a person may have an arbitrary number of random titles and they can't be neatly classified in a tree.)

Comment: @StuartF ***I'm*** aware of that (but you may not have been addressing my comment, which was focussed on the question). Mr/Mrs/Miss/Mx etc is one class; Dr/Prof/Mr/Mrs etc is another class; Sir/Dame another; military ranks another; religious titles another; lordly titles are another. Some supersede others; some are used alongside others. To encounter a Professor Cmdr Mrs Dame Jennifer Smith is at least possible.

Comment: In UK we call a surgeon (who is highly qualified) "Mister". OTOH I gather that school teachers in the USA are called "professor", which aggrandizement isn't used in UK except for the very top academics. So it's difficult to generalise on the usage of titles.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Actually, it isn't possible because Mr/Mrs/Miss would never be used alongside Sir/Dame because these titles are linked to the forename (knighthood pre-dates the use of hereditary surnames).

Comment: @KateBunting You're saying that "Dr Sir James Dibble" isn't possible? If it is, then a surgeon's title Mr/Mrs is equally possible (or impossible; I'm not sure which "title" you're referring to).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - No, I'm saying that "Mrs Dame Jennifer Smith" isn't possible (though "Professor Dame Jennifer Smith" is).

Comment: @KateBunting But it is possible, because Mrs is the honorific for a female surgeon. So "Dr Sir James Dibble" is essentially the same as "Mrs Dame Jennifer Smith".

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I suspect that surgeons drop the 'Mr/Mrs' on receiving a 'higher' title just as an ordinary Mr or Mrs would. I found an article on the eminent heart surgeon Magdi Yacoub which refers to him alternately as 'Sir Magdi' and 'Professor Yacoub'.

Comment: @tchrist, do I understand correctly that everything below the line in this question is your text, rather than the OPs? I thought that the questioners are on this site usually discouraged from using edits to the question to respond to the answers.

Comment: @jsw29 I simply hit the "Convert to Edit" button on the misplaced answer.

Comment: Introducing *President* in the edit changes the question: the conventions that govern the use of that title are different from the conventions that govern *Dr* and *Prof*. Even after the edit, it remains unclear what the motivation for the question is. Are you seeking practical advice on how to use these titles (in which case the question has a definite answer that is readily available elsewhere) or you already know that and are trying to accomplish something else? If the latter, what?

Comment: Related: [The usage of the title "Mr." along with other titles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381881).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not "sub-categories."  Note that in different circumstances, the same person may be addressed with any of the three titles you gave.  For example, suppose that John Smith has a doctorate in history, and is the incumbent of an endowed professorship at a university.  His students, who know he is a professor, will probably call him Professor Smith.  His graduate school, which does not know he is now a professor, will probably send him correspondence that begins "Dear Dr. Smith."  Meanwhile, the police officer who is writing him a summons for speeding on the highway will look at his driver's license (which has no titles) and will call him "Mr. Smith."

Comment: Of note: Driving licences in the UK do have honorifics and titles (which doesn't necessarily invalidate the answer)

Comment: What the examples in your answer illustrate is only that the people who **don't know** that somebody holds a higher title will be readily **excused** for using a lower one. That does not mean that the lower title should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Setting aside the OP's unusual use of the word *derivation*, the question here is whether male doctors and male professors are subsets of the set of misters. That is a very odd question to ask, because we practically never say that somebody is or isn't a mister. The word *mister* is used almost exclusively as a title, normally attached to the person's surname or full name.

As a general matter, people are addressed in English (unlike in, say, German) by at most one title, and that should be the highest title that the person holds. While there is sometimes room for dispute as to which of the titles is the highest one (they may not all belong to the same dimension, so to speak), *Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms* is always the lowest one (except in the peculiar use of these titles for surgeons in the UK, and some other places where the medical profession is organised along similar lines). If one is addressing someone in a formal way, one thus generally won't use *Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms*, if another title is available.

How such titles are actually used is common knowledge, and this question probably wouldn't belong to this site if it only sought a restatement of it. The question, as I understand it, is whether *Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms* **mean** somebody who does not hold any other title, so that using it for a person who does hold a higher title is ruled out as a matter of semantics, **or** that is not a part of their meanings, and not using it in such cases is merely a matter of **pragmatics**. This is not a question about actual usage, but of what way of conceptualising the facts of actual usage is better.

Like all such highly theoretical questions, one should not expect it to have a definite answer for which a definite, conclusive argument can be given. The choice between the two options depends on what way of conceptualising this fact will work better in the overall theoretical framework for our understanding of the language. For anybody to attempt to offer an argument about the matter, one would have to know far more about what motivated the OP to ask this question. In the absence of such an elaboration on part of the OP, I am inclined to respond that it doesn't matter whether one thinks of, say, *Mr* and *Dr* as mutually exclusive or overlapping concepts, as long as one is clear about what was said in the second paragraph of this answer about how these terms are actually used.

Comment: That's not the case. Multiple titles like "Professor Sir..." or "Admiral Lord" are pretty common.

Comment: @DJClayworth I remember in one of the Hornblower stories, a young foreign prince was serving as a midshipman. Hornblower settled on "Mister Prince So-and-so" as the proper address.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I said 'as a general matter'. At the time when I posted the answer, such exceptions had already been noted in Ms Bunting's comments below the question, and elaborating on them would be a distraction from dealing with the question. (The OP is not asking how to actually use various titles in English, but how to conceptualise the relationships between *Dr/Prof* on one side and *Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms* on the other.) In English, one would certainly never address someone as 'Mr Prof Dr Smith', while such forms of address would be standard in some other languages.

Answer (score -2):

**Title** is the main category or hypernym*
Doctor, Lord, Mister, Professor, General, King, etc is a sub-category or hyponym** of "title"

*Linguistics. = superordinate: a term that denotes a general class under which a set of subcategories is subsumed: “Child” is the superordinate of “girl” and “boy.”

**noun Linguistics.
a term that denotes a subcategory of a more general class:
“Chair” and “table” are hyponyms of “furniture.”

Comment: If *title* were a hypernym for *Doctor*, etc., one could begin a letter with 'Dear Title Smith'. The relationship of *title* to *doctor* is analogous to that of *noun* to *girl*, not to that of *child* to *girl*.